# ffmpeg webm encode for low powered devices

Tags: android, ffmpeg, webm

I want to play transparent video into my app using built-in player over phone's camera capture. I try to encode my video with alpha channel for android device:

`ffmpeg -i "Comp.avi" -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p -metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode="1" output.webm`

The result is pretty good, but I have lags (freezing video from time to time) while playing it on my android phone. Is it any **options to improve *decode* performance**?

Some console output:

```
D:\SOFT\ffmpeg-20160207-git-9ee4c89-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i "d:\temp\cherti\Comp 1.avi" -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p -metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode="1" d:\temp\cherti\output.webm
ffmpeg version N-80386-g5f5a97d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'd:\temp\cherti\Comp 1.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2017-02-18T14:10:42.00916
    encoder         : Adobe After Effects CC 2015 (Windows)
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1592542 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgra, 1080x1920, 1605907 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
File 'd:\temp\cherti\output.webm' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libvpx @ 0000000002593640] v1.5.0
[webm @ 00000000025a54e0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, webm, to 'd:\temp\cherti\output.webm':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2017-02-18T14:10:42.00916
    encoder         : Lavf57.38.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuva420p, 1080x1920, q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 1k tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 libvpx
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
```

Comment: The lags presented was in which device? I believe that depends of memory and resolution from device.

Comment: Default encoder for webm results in VP9. If your `ffmpeg` is old it will be VP8. Which is your command outputting? You should show the complete console output from your command. Maybe your device can handle VP8 easier if your output is VP9.

Comment: @DouglasFrari On Huawei P8 Max, but lags are only on default player. VLC plays it without any lags!

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yes, I have added console output to the question. Thank you.